# how to load 3 UIviews in one viewcontrollor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have working current modal contains one view controller in that view controller i have one `UITableview` contains three options. What i need is that i want add 3 `UIView` in same view controller respective to options is this possible to add three `UIViews` in the same view controller & one more thing if one view is selected means other two view should be hidden.

Hope i get some good coding from helper side.

I need something like this :

```
IBOutlet UITableView *table;
IBOutlet UIView *view1;
IBOutlet UIView *view2;
IBOutlet UIView *view3;

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (indexPath.row==0) {
    table.hidden=YES;
    view1.hidden=NO;
    view3.hidden=YES;
    view2.hidden=YES;
}else if (indexPath.row==1){
    view2.hidden=NO;
    view1.hidden=YES;
    view3.hidden=YES;
}else if (indexPath.row==2){
    view2.hidden=YES;
    view1.hidden=YES;
    view3.hidden=NO;
}
}
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: IF you want cells in tableview use UITableViewDataSource to give cell to your table
if you want to use UIViews in main view you cant hide/show your views as view1.hidden = YES; or NO

Comment: use `UISegmentedControl` for showing `Views` on selection of any `Index` you can `hide&show` your `views`

Comment: i am beginner can u suggest any codes ?

Comment: If you are hiding the table, you might want to just embed this view controller in a navigation controller and each view in a view controller.  Then you could push segue to the view controller you want and even go back to the table to change your selection.

Answer (score 0):

It's uncertain what your end goal is here, so i could be wrong but i'd be looking into creating storyboards for each of your views and linking then up to your tableview to get the desired effect you want.